# Unusually slow Azure table storage query?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a dotnet app running in Azure App Services and the Application Map in App Insights shows one noticeably slow connection:

- 393 calls to Redis av. 4.1ms
- 146 calls to readonly SQL server av. 11.6ms
- 102 calls to writable SQL server av. 24.2ms
- 17 calls to blob storage av. 98ms (mostly PUT of a 300Kish file)
- 31 calls to AWS Simple Email Service av. 185ms (external and known slow!)
- **42 calls to table storage av. 130ms**

The calls to table storage are divided into two queries, one that takes av. 100ms and one that takes average 160ms. The slower one simply calls `FetchAllAsync` e.g. no filter, on a table that has about 10 rows, each of which is very small.

Since the system is showing some pretty impressive latencies on other services, why would table storage be so slow relatively? Is `FetchAllAsync` slow? Other comments show latencies of 20-30ms so I don't think I am being too strict?

The C# code is simply `var results = await azureService.FetchAllAsync<ImageWrapper>("Images");` but this is image metadata, not images themselves.

Comment: Please read this article (if not done already): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-performance-checklist. Hopefully this will give you some ideas about the slowness.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have answered some of this since on another instance of the same app (production instead of system test), the latencies are much lower, so it would suggest it is environmental?

Comment: Considering you have not shared details about the environment and the code, it would be hard to comment for anybody as to what could be the reason for slowness. May I suggest you add more details to your question before it is closed for being unclear? Thanks.

Comment: The enviroment is App Services, as stated in the question, I added some code but I'm not sure what other details would be helpful. The real question is, "does anyone know why a simple call to a small Table storage table would be so slow on average?"